# GParted is not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gparted, fat32

I installed GParted to change format of my PD to FAT32. After installation I clicked on its icon and its asking for Authecatation. But, after that GParted is not running.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command in terminal: `xhost si:localuser:root`
Until you logout, sudo applications, like `gparted`, will work fine.

Thats a wayland feature, so alternatively you can login in Xorg session and gparted will work.

Or add this command to startup applications if you need to run root applications often.